# How to remove present color and get default color of an image using graphics in java

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics, event-handling

I have an image and then I use pre-defined position on it to create an oval with a color. Then I click on it again to remove the oval and color .

This is what I've already done for the objective,

**ImagePanel.java**

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel{
    private Image img;

    public ImagePanel(String img, String str){
        //this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());    
    }

    public ImagePanel(String path){
        Image img = new ImageIcon(path).getImage();
        this.img = img;
        Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
        setPreferredSize(size);
        setMinimumSize(size);
        setMaximumSize(size);
        setSize(size);
        setLayout(null);

         try{
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
            int rgb = image.getRGB(66, 52);
            System.out.println("Colour is: "+rgb);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Then I use it as below,

```
public class PrintDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog{

private int count = 0;

/**
 * Creates new form PrintDialog
 */
public PrintDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal){
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
    ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel("example.jpg");
    this.getContentPane().add(panel);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(panel);
    this.pack();
}


private void formMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt){                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    System.out.println("Print y - " + evt.getY());
    System.out.println("Print x - " + evt.getX());

    if ((evt.getX() >= 68 && evt.getX() <= 84) && (evt.getY() >= 44 && evt.getY() <= 72)){

        count++;
        if (count == 1){
            System.out.println("Count - 1");
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(66, 52, 20, 20);

        } else if (count > 1){
            g.setColor(new Color(-3692899));
            System.out.println("Min - 2");
            g.fillOval(66, 52, 20, 20);
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    g.dispose();
}
}
```

But finally I couldn't get default color of the position when I click on it at the second time. Which means, I can't remove the oval I created.

Have any ideas please? .

Thank you .

Comment: Don't use getGraphics, ever, this is not how custom painting works

Comment: start with `super.paintComponent(g);` as 1.st code line inside `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {`, then mouse event must to call `repaint();

Comment: The answer to your question lies in my first comment. You should be using paintComponent to perform custom painting

Comment: @MadProgrammer : I want to remove the oval or change the color of it .

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm totally confused. Any coding support please?

Comment: @mKorbel: I am actually confused after days of trying this. Any edits or code hints would be great.

Comment: @mKorbel : Your idea worked for me . Thank you very much .

Comment: @Barrier you are welcome

Comment: If you're still using `getGraphics`, try resizing the window after you've painted the circle...